# Compose for Desktop LazyRow/LazyColumn not scrolling with mouse click

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-desktop

For some reason `LazyColumn`s do not scroll with a mouse click and move gesture. It only works with the mouse wheel so far. For `LazyRow`s it is also not possible to scroll with the mouse wheel. It seems that lazy row is useless for Compose for desktop.

Are there any possiblities to enable a click and move gesture on `LazyRow` and `LazyColum`. And if not is it at least possible to enable to scroll through a `LazyRow` with the mouse wheel?

I used this minimal reproducible example to test the scrolling

```
@Composable
@Preview
fun App() {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("Hello, World!") }

    MaterialTheme {
        LazyRow(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            repeat(100) {
                item {
                    Text("Test Test Test Test $it    ")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fun main() = application {
    Window(onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication) {
        App()
    }
}
```

Comment: For desktop you might want to consider using scrollbars instead of dragging: 
https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/tree/master/tutorials/Desktop_Components#scrollbars

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is the intended behavior.

All scrollable components (including `LazyColumn`) work (for now) only with mouse wheel scroll events on the desktop.
The scrollable components should not respond to mouse drag/move events.

Here's a basic example of how you can add drag support to your components:

```
val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
LazyRow(
    state = scrollState,
    modifier = Modifier
        .draggable(
            orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
            state = rememberDraggableState { delta ->
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    scrollState.scrollBy(-delta)
                }
            },
        )
) {
    items(100) {
        Text("Test Test Test Test $it")
    }
}
```

Comment: so much complexity for this easy behaviour, I hope this will get simplified soon

Comment: how can I make this work for LazyColumn?

When I try, I get this:


Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:


public fun Modifier.draggable(state: DraggableState, orientation: Orientation, enabled: Boolean = ..., interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource? = ..., startDragImmediately: Boolean = ..., onDragStarted: suspend CoroutineScope.(startedPosition: Offset) → Unit

Comment: @rosualin there's nothing changed since this answer has being created, make sure you have correct imports - maybe you've imported `Orientation` from a wrong package?

Comment: This exact code works for me, but not for LazyColumn. Weird that LazyRow can find Draggable but not LazyColumn :-?

Comment: @rosualin if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with gist I may be able to help you

Comment: Sorry for the late response.

this is how I use it:
https://pastebin.com/q3qtSLA5

I included also the imports I use for that (foundation.gestures)

I even tried removing the "Tab" and just keeping the row from inside it, then I have no clickable on my "tabs" but still I cannot click and drag with my mouse

Comment: It was due to the ScrollableTabRow. I ditched that for chromebooks and just use a LazyRow and works